# How does Math.random() generate random numbers beyond it's "native" range?

Tags: java, random

I understand that `Math.random()` by itself generates a random double between 0.0 and 1.0, including 0.0 but excluding 1.0. I also understand that casting to an int truncates everything after the decimal without rounding.

What I don't understand is how something like

```
System.out.println((int)(Math.random() * 27));
```

can actually produce a random number from 0 through 26. Since `Math.random()` by itself only produces 0.0 through 0.9, and 9 * 27 is 24.3, it seems like the greatest int the above code should be able to produce is 24. How does this work?

Through searching for answers to this I have discovered that there are better ways to generate random numbers, but the book I am working through describes this particular method, and I'd like to understand how it works.

Comment: Wait, you say _generates a random double between 0.0 and 1.0, including 0.0 but excluding 1.0._ and _Math.random() by itself only produces 0.0 through 0.9_. Which one is it? There's a lot of stuff between `0.9` and `1.0`.

Comment: Well 0.9 is not the max it generates.

Comment: I believe there are 2^52 (or maybe 2^52+1) different possible numbers in the [0.0, 1.0) interval that `Math.random()` can generate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The range of [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) isn't `0.0` through `0.9`, it's `0.0` through the greatest possible `double` less than `1.0`, about 0.9999999999999999 or so.

> **Returns:**
>
> a pseudorandom double greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

If you multiply the largest possible result by `27` and truncate it by casting to `int`, you will get `26`.

Comment: Oh man, you were one 9 away from the actual canonical toString representation of that greatest-number-closer-than-1.0! :) (the exact number is 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875).

Comment: @yshavit Thanks for pointing that out.  I meant to have 16 9s.  Updated.

Answer (score 4):

> Since Math.random() by itself only produces 0.0 through 0.9

This statement is incorrect. [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) produces a random number in the range of [0, 1). This means that the upper bound isn't 0.9 - it can produce 0.99, 0.999, 0.9999 or any decimal number arbitrarily close to 1. Just as an example, `27 * 0.99` is 26.73, which is truncated down to `26`.

Answer (score 3):

You read the specifications of `Math.random` wrong.

The numbers that can be generated are **between `0.0` (inclusive) and `1.0` (exclusive)**. But it can also produce something `0.99999` ish.

Since you multiply with `27` it will give you a number between `0.0` (inclusive) and `27` (exclusive). The maximum number that can be generated is thus `26.99999999...`.

Later in the process, you make a cast to an integer: `(int)`. This cast **takes the integral part**, so although the result can be `26.999999...`, `26` is used.

A final remark is that *Java* has a decent [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class, that provides some functionality to generate integer numbers. For instance [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) where you can give the maximum (exclusive) number.